# Remove duplicate files in a directory

Tags: batch-file

I have a working script, *(below)*, which compares files, by size only, and if one or more of the files have different size, it shows on the [`.bat` screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbW4w.jpg).

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Group all file names by size
for /R %%a in (*.*) do (
   set "size[%%~Za]=!size[%%~Za]!,%%~Fa"
)

rem Show groups that have more than one element
for /F "tokens=2,3* delims=[]=," %%a in ('set size[') do (
   if "%%c" neq "" echo [%%a]: %%b,%%c
)
pause
```

But I need more!

I also need the script delete duplicate files, keeping just one. For example, if there are `3` files of the same size but with different names, the script should choose one to keep, deleting the other `2`.

---

@LotPings, i tried with 2 .pdf files, and appeared this message in the pic below:

[image: Error]

---

@LotPings

Now it recognized fine! But it doesn't deleting the duplicate, just recognizing.... Look the image below:

[image]

Comment: William, this is not how Stack Overflow works, the idea is that you seek help with a script which is supposed to perform a task but somehow fails to successfully do as intended. Your question is no different to, 'I have this working script, DEL *.CSV, but I now need it need it to search each file and read fields `2`, `4` and `7` on every line, and if any of the those contain a date within the last `7` days in the format `ddd-MMM-yyyy`, do not delete it'! Make an attempt at the task edit your question with the attempted script and ask a specific question about any issues it exhibits; thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I think treating files with same size as same content is a bit naive.
  If in doubt better do a binary compare with fc.
- Your way of stuffing `%%~Fa` into a string without quoting every single name possibly containing spaces can be problematic in further processing.
- If the files **are** identical you could create links.
- You **know** that `for /r` will recurse into subdirs?

The following batch will process the `size[]` array differently passing the size and content to a subroutine which keeps the first file and (only echos) the del command.

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\06\06\SO_50723488.cmd
@echo off & setlocal
rem Group all file names by size
for /R %%a in (*.*) do call set size[%%~Za]=%%size[%%~Za]%%,"%%~Fa"

rem Process groups
for /F "tokens=2* delims=[]=," %%a in ('set size[') do Call :Sub %%a %%b

pause
Goto :Eof

:Sub
If "%~3"=="" (Set "size[%1]="&goto :EOf)
Echo ========================================
Echo processing %*
Echo Keep %2
Shift&shift

:loop
Echo Del  %1
if not "%~2"=="" (shift&goto :loop)
```

Sample output:

```
> Q:\Test\2018\06\06\SO_50723488.cmd
========================================
processing 0 "Q:\Test\2018\05\03\Text3.txt","Q:\Test\2018\05\27\log.html"
Keep "Q:\Test\2018\05\03\Text3.txt"
Del  "Q:\Test\2018\05\27\log.html"
========================================
processing 14 "Q:\Test\2018\05\03\Text1.txt","Q:\Test\2018\05\15\HP-G1610-20180515.json"
Keep "Q:\Test\2018\05\03\Text1.txt"
Del  "Q:\Test\2018\05\15\HP-G1610-20180515.json"
========================================
processing 21 "Q:\Test\2018\05\12\text1.txt","Q:\Test\2018\05\12\text2.txt"
Keep "Q:\Test\2018\05\12\text1.txt"
Del  "Q:\Test\2018\05\12\text2.txt"
========================================
processing 22 "Q:\Test\2018\05\20\2.txt","Q:\Test\2018\05\22\version.ps1"
Keep "Q:\Test\2018\05\20\2.txt"
Del  "Q:\Test\2018\05\22\version.ps1"
========================================
processing 288 "Q:\Test\2018\05\11\RawData.txt","Q:\Test\2018\05\23\SO_50478080.ps1"
Keep "Q:\Test\2018\05\11\RawData.txt"
Del  "Q:\Test\2018\05\23\SO_50478080.ps1"
```

Comment: Then change `for /R %%a in (*.*) ...` to `for /R %%a in (*.pdf) ...` , but that should be infornation edited into your question not in comments

Comment: take a look on my question

Comment: Changed code to remove outer quotes with `~` when comparing, this should remove the error.

Comment: While testing I didn't want to delee **my** files so I inserted an echo to only show what would be deleted, read my answer I already mentioned this. The final pause comand allows to see the output and stems fom your own code. If you find an answer helpful you should consider to [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) and/or [vote up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)

Answer (score 0):

The following script removes duplicate files in the current directory. It leaves one file, and removes rest of its duplicates. I developed the script for Windows 10, so it might not work for other Windows versions.

The advantage of this script is it not only checks the last modified date and time, but also the file size. Let's say you have a text file with *** symbols? you can turn them all ### symbols, and still occupy the same space. The script checks the last modified date, and time along with its size to ensure both the files are identical, otherwise it doesn't remove any file.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
echo(
echo "This program removes duplicate files in the current directory."
echo "Warning: Take a backup of the current directory to avoid accidents"
PAUSE
echo(
set path=%cd%
set /A count=0

for %%a in (*.*) do (
    for %%b in (*.*) do (
        if exist "%%b" if %%a neq %%b (
            if "%%~Ta %%~Za" equ "%%~Tb %%~Zb" (
                echo "%%a File is deleted"
                set /A count+=1
                del "%%a"
            )
        )
    )
)

echo(
echo "---------"
echo "!count! Duplicate Files were deleted in the current directory"
echo "---------"
echo(

endlocal
PAUSE
```

If you have any problems report me at
https://github.com/donqq/Duplicate-File-Remover/